# Using localStorage to remember a list view

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, local-storage

I'm relatively new to Javascript. Often kludged, rarely written, yadda yadda. So my current task is to create a list and have it swap between a standard list or a grid item view. That part I've more or less figured out – what I haven't is how to make it so the state is remembered between reloads and multiple pages (our list paginates).

Here's the components of the code:

**HTML**

```
<strong>View</strong>
    <div class="view">
        <a href="#" id="grid">List</a>
        <a href="#" id="list">Grid</a> 
    </div>
<div class="display">
<?php 
$temp = $wp_query; 
$wp_query = null; 
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
$wp_query->query('showposts=24&order=ASC&post_type=review'.'&paged='.$paged); 

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>
<div class="item list">
    <div class="thumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'thumbnail' ); ?>"></a></div>
    <div class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    <div class="author"><p>By <a href="<?php the_author(); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></p></div>
    <div class="date"><?php the_date('d-m-Y'); ?></div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list').click(function(event){event.preventDefault();$('.item').addClass('grid');});localStorage.setItem('.item', grid);
    $('#grid').click(function(event){event.preventDefault();$('.item').removeClass('grid');localStorage.setItem('.item', list);
    (localStorage.getItem('.item') == 'grid') {

});
```

Any help regarding what I'm doing wrong or how to better understand the issue would be greatly appreciated. Again, I'm new to this whole .js thing, so I apologize if the above is just *atrocious* script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work. *(to get localstorage working run it outside of StackOverflow sandbox)*

Basically you just want to save the last known state of the view as a string either **'grid'** or **'list'**

And apply the value as a class on ***$(document).ready()***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#list').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $('.item').addClass('list')
    $('.item').removeClass('grid')
    localStorage.setItem('.item', 'list');
  });
  $('#grid').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.item').addClass('grid')
    $('.item').removeClass('list')
    localStorage.setItem('.item', 'grid')
  })
  let itemClass = localStorage.getItem('.item')
  $('.item').addClass(itemClass)
});
```

```css
.item.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.item.list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="list">List</button>
<button id="grid">Grid</button>

<br/>
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
<div class="item">Item 5</div>
<div class="item">Item 6</div>
<div class="item">Item 7</div>
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much Codeseer!